# How to check if NSMutableArray object contains NaN

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, ios7

I have an NSMutableArray with 1 float value and 4 nan values. I want to execute some operations if the array object is nan. How can I write an if condition?

Comment: do you want to check that whether array contains any object or not!!!????

Comment: What do you mean by *"if the array object is none"* ?

Comment: @MartinR Sorry, errata mistake!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try isnan function

Iterate your array and put check

`isnan([[Array objectAtIndex:i] floatValue])`

(dont forget to add math.h library)

Comment: Right, let me correct it

Comment: isnan([[array objectAtIndex:i] floatValue]) worked like a charm! without math.h import.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSNumber *num = //your number;
float value = [num floatValue];
if (isnan(value))
{
    NSLog(@"is nan");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];
[array addObject:[NSNull null]];
[array addObject:[NSNull null]];
[array addObject:[NSDecimalNumber notANumber]];


BOOL foundNull = NO;
for (id value in array) {
    if (!value || value == [NSNull null]) {
        foundNull = YES;
    } else if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSDecimalNumber class]]) {
        if ([value isEqualToNumber:[NSDecimalNumber notANumber]]) {
            foundNull = YES;
        }
    }
}

NSLog(@"Found null/NaN: %i", foundNull);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

[[NSDecimalNumber notANumber]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000179-notANumber) method to compare and check if this a valid number or not.